# Multiple `rules` clause in GitLab CI config

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have many rules in my CI config, and also many anchors.
It's not an offence to the linter to mention `rules:` multiple times per job, but the same linter does not help with testing whether multiple `rules:` clauses add up and in which order.

So the trouble is, now I have to repeat the slightly changing set of rules in every job.

```
.build-rules:                      &build-rules
  rules:
    - if: '$DEPLOY_TAG'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ "/^v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.*$/"'

job_with_changed_rule:
  <<:               *build-rules
  rules:
    - if: '$DEPLOY_TAG'
  script:
    - do something

job_with_another_rule:
  <<:               *build-rules
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
  script:
    - do something else
```

Answer (score 3):

Before Gitlab 14.3 the only thing you could do was placing `extends` block

But now you can re-use rules from other jobs with `!reference` tag.

For more details see this [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#reuse-rules-in-different-jobs)